# Typescript class property initialized in constructor and undefined in member function

Tags: typescript, electron, eventemitter

I keep running into the same issue over and over again.  I am creating an electron app using Typescript.  I have a set of controllers for the back end.  The AppController has jurisdiction over the interaction with the file system.  The WindowController has jurisdiction over all the basic window functionality.  Here is a simplified version of the code:

AppController.ts

```
export class AppController {

  windowCtrl: WindowController

  constructor() {
    this.windowCtrl = new WindowController(Init Details);

    this.windowCtrl.windowEvents.on('window:get-parent-directory',
    () => {
      console.log('made it here');
    });
  }
}
```

WindowController.ts

```
export class WindowController {

  public windowEvents: EventEmitter;

  constructor(Init Details) {
    this.windowEvents = new EventEmitter();
    // this.windowEvents is defined here.
    ipcMain.on('get-parent', getParentDirecotry);
  }

  getParentDirectory() {
    this.windowEvents.emit('window:get-parent-directory');
    // this.windowEvents is undefined here
  }
}
```

The event emitter **windowEvents** is communicating between the two classes via messages.  I have done this same thing with EventEmitters in Angular and I read through the node documentation to ensure that I did not make a stupid mistake.  I have done quite a bit of research, but all I found was example of people not initializing it in the constructor.  I'm out of options and don't know what I'm missing.  This same issue happened with an instance of a BrowserWindow from electron.  I initialize it in the constructor, the window is open on the screen, and when I try and call it from a member function of the class it is undefined.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your code is correct, but something is `undefined` without a reason, it may be because you ran into the *circular dependency* problem.

The tool you're using to build your project may have found two modules that are — directly or indirectly — dependent on each other. To resolve the situation, it has to start somewhere, but for the price of temporarily marking one module one as `undefined`.

You can verify if that's the case by using static analysis. If you're using TSLint, the [`tslint-no-circular-imports`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-no-circular-imports) rule offers just that. There is also a [Webpack plugin](https://github.com/aackerman/circular-dependency-plugin) that does the same thing.

Comment: Hi Karol,  Thanks for answering.  I added the no-circular-import rule but it didn't hit on anything.  Makes me think that isn't the problem, but I'm still hitting the issue...

Comment: At least we eliminated one possible cause. Would you be willing to create a reduced repository that demonstrates the issue?